# Automatically format words in a PDFLaTeX document which are in a keyword list

Tags: pdftex, keywords

When writing technical documents, I often want to format 'technical phrases' (such as the name of some technology) in a particular way, which becomes annoying when I type the phrases frequently.

I'm wondering if there's a way I could define a list of 'keywords' in my LaTeX document which, when encountered else in the document, are automatically formatted in a particular way (which I would define).

For example, instead of the current method of:

```
The \textbf{gmond} daemon is the blurst. I hate \textbf{gmond} and \textbf{gmetad}.
```

I could write something which could look like

```
\keywords{gmond, gmetad}{\textbf}

The gmond daemon is the blurst. I hate gmond and gmetad.
```

which would produce identical output as above.

Is this at all possible? I'm happy to have to write `\gmond`, as long as I don't have to define the command for each word in my keywords list.

Comment: if you are prepared to use  `the \gmond\ daemon is the blurst. I hate \gmond\ and \gmetad.` then it is easy to set up, if you want it without markup then it's possible (there are some answers on site) but more fragile and possibly easier with lualatex than classic latex.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I'm fine to use `\gmond`, as long as I don't have to do `\newcommand{\gmond}{\textbf}` for every keyword.

Comment: See [format special words in text](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/107014) and [Highlight every occurrence of a list of words?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/248632)

Comment: Another way would to use `\lstinline` with special styles and define a new 'language' with this keywords.

Comment: See also [Macro for typesetting acronyms](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/9487/3083).

Comment: Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/238795/automatically-highlight-words-from-a-predefined-list

Comment: Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/280532/is-there-a-way-to-have-xesearch-search-and-replace-a-term-and-have-the-replaceme

Answer (score 6):

Here's a `keywordmarkup` generator way with `expl3` (note: Keywords, not key phrases)

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\clist_new:N \l_antiearth_keywords_clist

\newcommand{\keywordslist}[2]{%
  \clist_set:Nn \l_antiearth_keywords_clist {#1}
  \clist_map_inline:Nn \l_antiearth_keywords_clist {%
    \expandafter\newcommand\csname ##1\endcsname{{#2 ##1}}
  }
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\keywordslist{gmond, gmetad}{\bfseries}

Here is an example with \gmond\ and \gmetad. 

\end{document}
```

**Update**

Use different lists (the style handling is not very well yet)

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\keywordslist}{mmm}{%
  \clist_new:c {l_antiearth_#1_clist}
  \clist_set:cn {l_antiearth_#3_clist} {#2}
  \clist_map_inline:cn {l_antiearth_#3_clist} {%
    \expandafter\NewDocumentCommand\csname ##1\endcsname{}{{\csname #3\endcsname ##1}}
  }
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\keywordslist{boldlist}{gmond, gmetad}{bfseries}
\keywordslist{italiclist}{other, nope}{itshape}

Here is an example with \gmond\ and \gmetad.

Here is an example with \other\  and \nope.


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1, but please use `\NewDocumentCommand` for the document level function `\keywordslist` to have it automatically e-TeX protected and call a code level function from there rather than doing everything inside the document level function.

Comment: @HenriMenke: Yes, I was in a hurry;-) I am updating this

Comment: This seems to remove the space after gmond on Ubuntu, and I can't add the space back after `\bfseries`. Will I have to write `\gmond{}`? That stinks

Comment: (+1.) @AntiEarth -- Load the package `xspace`, and change `\endcsname ##1}}` to `\endcsname ##1}\xspace}`.  However, `xspace` can have some (fairly minor but) unfortunate kerning side effects.

Comment: @AntiEarth: That's the problem of any macro basically.

Comment: With your solution, define `section`, `chapter`, `alpha`,  or `document` as keywords may be problematic!

Comment: @PaulGaborit: Of course, but as long as no description of the 'language' is available ... and I have another solution in mind, I try to update this soon

Answer (score 3):

You can add items to a list and replace the words in the argument to a command.  You can add items with

```
\keywords{comma separated list}{\text…}
```

where `\text…` has to be one single command which takes exactly one parameter.  The replacement is done with

```
\applykeywords{text}
```

Because `text` is split at the spaces one has to take punctuation into account, see example below.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\tl_new:N \g_anti_keywords

\cs_new_protected:Npn \anti_add_keywords:nN #1#2
 {
  \clist_map_inline:nn { #1 }
   {
    \tl_gput_right:Nn \g_anti_keywords {{##1}{#2{##1}}}
   }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Npn \anti_apply_keywords:n #1
 {
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_tmpa_seq { ~ } { #1 }
  \seq_map_inline:Nn \l_tmpa_seq
   {
    \str_case:nVF { ##1 } \g_anti_keywords { ##1 } ~
   }
   \tex_unskip:D
 }

\NewDocumentCommand \keywords { m m }
 {
  \anti_add_keywords:nN { #1 } #2
 }

\NewDocumentCommand \applykeywords { m }
 {
  \anti_apply_keywords:n { #1 }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\keywords{gmond, gmetad}{\textbf}
\keywords{blurst., gmetad.}{\textit}

\applykeywords{The gmond daemon is the blurst. I hate gmond and gmetad.}
\end{document}
```

> [image]

Comment: What purpose is served by having the document level command call a combo-command sequence rather than just using the commands in that combo directly? I guess I don't quite understand the idea behind this split since, to the uninformed, it just seems to make the code (1) longer and (2) more opaque as it is that much more difficult to figure out what a document command does and how it does it. (First find the command in the source. Then find the combo-thing the command calls. Then figure out what the combined things combine to do.) Is the extra layer more efficient (faster) or safer or...?

Comment: @cfr The point is, that you [can't patch or `\let` xparse defined commands](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/285551/how-to-let-an-xparse-defined-command).  Thus a person who wants to extend `\keywords` has to do a `\RenewDcoumentCommand \keywords { m m } { \anti_add_keywords:nN { #1 } #2 … do more stuff … }`.  This is more convenient than having to copy a huge code block.

Answer (score 1):

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper,fleqn,parskip=half]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc} 
\usepackage{bookman} 
\newcommand{\gm}{\textbf{gmond}}
\newcommand{\gt}{\textbf{gmetad}}

\begin{document}

The \gm\ daemon is the blurst. I hate \gm\ and \gt.

\end{document}
```

However, and responding to @Anti Earth's just criticism of the above, xelatex ([thanks to @jfbu](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/280532/is-there-a-way-to-have-xesearch-search-and-replace-a-term-and-have-the-replaceme)) seems to do this quite well in a minimalist sort of way:

```
\documentclass {article}
\usepackage {fontspec}
\setmainfont {TeX Gyre Schola} 
\usepackage{soul}
\usepackage{color}
\sethlcolor{yellow}
\usepackage{xesearch}   
\UndoBoundary{-}
\SearchList{phrases}{\hl{#1}}{555-222-1212,Fido,Tinkerbell}
\robustify{\hl}
\SearchList{poems}{\textbf{#1}}{theatre,convention,Timbuktu}
\SearchList{advice}{\textit{#1}{productive,conductive,inductive}

  \begin{document}

    Once upon a time Tinkerbell called the Fairy Princess, at 555-222-1212, to complain that Fido was tinkling on the pretty flowers.
    \bigskip

    Away from the town of Timbuktu

    The theatre of the wise

    And the convention of the poor

    Combined to make the party
    \bigskip

    Your counsel is to only be seen as productive if conductive to proper inductive reasoning.

  \end{document}
```

which produces:

[image]

Comment: See "I'm happy to have to write \gmond, as long as I don't have to define the command for each word in my keywords list."

Comment: Yes I know.  Sometimes the simplest solutions are best.

Comment: @Anti Earth, per your suggestion, I changed the answer.

Comment: Is there any equivalent for PDFLatex?

Comment: perhaps one can link to your question https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/280532/is-there-a-way-to-have-xesearch-search-and-replace-a-term-and-have-the-replaceme

Comment: @Anti Earth I am not sure of that.  Recently I have been using the abbrevs package, but I have not investigated whether it will do command substitution like xesearch does in xetex.

Comment: @jfbu great idea, how would I link a question like that.

Comment: @jfbu added a link to the answer.  Is there a way to link otherwise?

Comment: @Anti Earth see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/289713/what-packages-provide-text-command-substitution-for-latex-xetex-and-luatex-lual

Comment: @jfbu see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/289713/what-packages-provide-text-command-substitution-for-latex-xetex-and-luatex-lual

Comment: ok, but I have no answer for your [new question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/289713/what-packages-provide-text-command-substitution-for-latex-xetex-and-luatex-lual) ;-) about links you probably already know that you can either paste directly the `http://...` thing or use `[name](url)` mark-up. Short links are provided by the "share" buttons.

Comment: Thanks @jfbu, I started out with xesearch, I use abbrevs when I have to use pdftex or luatex, then I ran into chickenize, did a search found xstring, and that's when I realized that I had no idea how many others were lurking out there.